# Best possible way to display 6 tabs with first 3 as mandatory steps and rest activated after completion of first 3?

Tags: tabs, wizard, states

[image]

We are revamping the attached page.We are using Angular Material framework.Requirement are as follows : 
1. User needs to fill form in first three tab as mandate like a wizard or stepper. (Expected Details,Arrived Details & Berthing Details)
2. After Berthing details are filled, the rest of the three tabs are activated and user can choose to fill any of the remaining form.
3. Once any form is filled and saved in tabs, user can go back to it at any time for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make a deliberate choice to use tabs instead of a paginated(stepped) form? I ask because you're introducing a concept that is new to new me. Having tabs that aren't available until other information is filled out creates deactivated deactivated tabs. Deactivated once because they are not the active tab then again because they are not available. I would try to avoid this and just using previous and next pagination is my first suggestion.

Comment: I have attached a page that we are trying to revamp completely.So, I'm open to all suggestion/ideas.